# How can I permanently force Xerox secure printing?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, printing

My clients are printing direct to a network printer (no print server).

Xerox have confirmed that the Secure Print Only option is only available in Windows, so I am looking at editing .plists, Applescript, Automator and anything else that can allow me to force my client Macs to default to secure printing.

Setting a preset only saves the 'system' settings, not the Xerox features. CUPs has an option to set defaults for the secure printing job type, but not, is seems, to set the default job type.

They suggested editing the PPD file would work but they will not support it. This is outside of my area of expertise but I can get it developed if pointed in the right direction.

A standalone automator app or system service would also be a suitable work around. Might we be able to enforce "secure printing" from OS X?

Comment: What is your printer exact model and OSX version?

Comment: I don't think it's possible: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15217825

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's outside the scope of Apple HW/SW and is more related to [CUPS Postscript Printer Driver (PPD) Development](https://www.cups.org/doc/postscript-driver.html)

Answer (score -1):

In Windows there is an opportunity to save individual, but permanent default settings for each application.  I'm sure the same option is there for Mac users as well.

Open the print driver settings.  Do the necessary adjustemnts to black-white vs color, one-sided or two-sided printing eg, and choose secure print.  The before pressing "print" choose the "save print defualts" ....  (I'm nt a Mac user so I cannot say where precisely that option is found.)

Comment: From the question: "Xerox have confirmed that the Secure Print Only option is only available in Windows". Which "secure print" otion are you refering to here?